# Why an impact exerts so much force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, material-science, continuum-mechanics

If an object of velocity $v$ and mass $m$ moves towards a resting object of mass $M$, then if the object which is hit might break. Why?

What is the reason that a collision has more power than a statical force $F$ acting on this object?

I haven't found any literature where such things are modeled. Can someone give literature where such things are described mathematically?

Comment: What do you mean "a collision has more power than a statical force $F$"? Depending how short the interval is in which the impulse is transferred, the forces acting during the collision will be far larger than what you can typically exert statically. Its not really clear to me what the question here is.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this, use the definition of force $\frac{d{\bf p}}{dt} = {\bf F}$, namely the force is equal to the rate of change of momentum. Something like a collision can be very complicated to model, but the *average force* is approximately given by ${\bf F}_{average} = \frac{\text{change in momentum}}{\text{time taken}}$. Typically, in a collision, the change of momentum is just the initial momentum, since afterwards the bodies are at rest. So, for any collisions, if you assume that the time taken for the collision is about the same (and can be of the order milli to tenths of a second), you get bigger (average) forces when the momentum change is bigger, namely when the initial momentum is larger. As an aside, not really useful to think of this as a problem in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Why the collision time is so short??? This I really don't understand. Also, as I studied the Boltzmann equation, something I didn't understand; the time scales used and how to make assumptions for the gas particle collision, etc.

Comment: If you ignore the collision time (very dependent on the collision), the important thing is that the change in momentum will be initial momentum - final momentum, and if the final momentum is zero, then the size of the force will depend on the initial momentum. The following may be useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7dG9UlzeFM

Comment: Nice answer.  You could add an example: a cup might break if you throw a stone at it. If you put something like a spring at it, it survives. In both cases the same momentum is transferred but in different collision times. Without the spring, the force might almost diverge due to the short time.

Answer (score 0):

Although the average force applied during a collision might be small enough that an object can take it, the peak force applied can be much higher. In physics this is called [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_%28physics%29).

Calculating the impulse for real world collisions (like a car crash) is very complicated. This is because cars have many structural members and the materials are not uniform. Depending on exactly how two objects collide, the forces can be applied to different members in different proportions and distributed around the object in different ways. This can cause forces to become concentrated on certain members, making them fail.

Comment: And why the collision time with two objects built up by metal or stone should be shorter (therefore more force) than for softer materials (e.g. rubber)?

Comment: In the case of rubber vs stone, it has to do with the elasticity of the materials. Rubber is able to deform much more than stone, so the force of the impact gets spread out over a longer time.

Comment: A collision begins when the objects first make contact, but at first only the atoms at the surface are displaced.  The object as a whole does not move until the influence of that original atomic displacement propagates throughout the solid.  That happens at the speed of sound which is faster for hard materials.